# Which dual lands count as having the name of their respective basic land types for certain effects?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example, let's take a look at [Arbor Elf](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArbor%20Elf%5d), which has the ability "T: Untap target Forest"

Which types of dual lands count as a [Forest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bForest%5d) and thus can be untapped by Arbor Elf?

Is there a comprehensive heuristic I can use for this? I've never actually seen the rule anywhere and these lands never mention that fact, nor have I seen it in errata or card rulings. But apparently it's a thing because I heard it mentioned in forums and cards that mention basic lands have worked on some dual lands before in MTGA.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's an assumption you're making that's a bit off here, that assumption being that you are looking for something by name. [Voltaic Key](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVoltaic%20Key%5d) has the ability "[image: {1}], [image: {T}]: Untap target artifact." that does not untap a card named artifact, but a card with the type artifact.

In the case of Arbor Elf, untap target forest refers to cards with the subtype forest, Dual lands such as [Breeding Pool](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBreeding%20Pool%5d) and [Scattered Groves](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bScattered%20Groves%5d) both have forest on their type line, and can be targeted. Even a few single colored non basic lands like [Dryad Arbor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDryad%20Arbor%5d) and [Sapseep Forest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSapseep%20Forest%5d) count, as they have forest in their type line.

We can see this method more clearly in cards like [Nissa's Pilgrimage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNissa%27s%5d%2b%5bPilgrimage%5d), which specifies basic forests, or [Cabal Stronghold](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCabal%20Stronghold%5d) which specifies basic swamps. Specifying the supertype basic in addition to the subtype forest/swamp/etc means you can only find this info on the type line, though they could have said lands named forest or lands named swamp and got roughly the same result.

In addition to cards like this, there are effects that change the type of land, or turn things into lands, effects like [Urborg, Tomb of Yawgmoth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUrborg%2c%20Tomb%20of%20Yawgmoth%5d) would make all lands swamps, so they would count for anything that looks at swamps, such as [Cabal Coffers](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCabal%20Coffers%5d), and [Life and Limb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLife%20and%20Limb%5d) makes all creatures with the subtype saproling into forests (and vice versa) turning them all into creature land - saproling forest.

Currently there are [25 cards that are printed as forests](https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=type:forest), 2 of these are the basic lands (regular and snow covered) the other 23 are non-basics. For the other 4 basic land types, there are: [23 Plains](https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=type:plains), [23 Islands](https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=type:island), [23 Swamps](https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=type:swamp), and [23 Mountains](https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=type:mountain). Generally these cards exist in cycles that have the same number of each, Dryad Arbor and [Murmuring Bosk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMurmuring%20Bosk%5d) are the 2 exceptions, forests without a matching cycle in other colors.

Comment: I like this answer for the emphasis it puts on the difference between "Forest" as a card name and "Forest" as a subtype. One thing that might be nice to have, but is certainly not necessary, is an example of how an ability that untaps a card named "Forest" would be worded, e.g. "T: Untap target land named Forest". (I don't think there's an actual example of this, but I'm extrapolating from other abilities that reference cards with specific names.)

Comment: @DavidZ Not targeting, but Nissa's Encouragement has "Search your library and graveyard for _a card named Forest_ [...]" versus Nature's Lore having "Search your library for _a Forest card_ [...]".

Comment: It seems to me that if a card says "target something, something" or "a something, something", unless otherwise specified the "something, something" refers exclusively to colour or (sub)type. Common specifications are "card / permanent / spell _named_ something, something" or "card / permanent / spell with _converted mana cost_ something, something". You don't see "with the colour red" or "with the type basic land" (or more correctly "the supertype basic and the type land"), they just say "red" or "basic land". I wonder whether that's specified in the rules somewhere.

Comment: @DavidZ Actually most of the time cards that work that way still refer to type, they reference a "basic forest" combining the supertype basic with the subtype forest as in [Nissa, Vastwood Seer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439341)'s ETB effect.

Comment: @Arthur as a general rule, cards are specific if they mean to be, if they mean basic forest they will say that, so the application is to use the broadest possible set that includes cards, in this case it's subtypes. The big exception is a card referring to its own name means this copy and only this copy, and that carries over to cards that copy the ability or clones like [Sakashima, the Imposter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=74509) which change the name, it's still self referential.

Comment: @Andrew My point was that when they are specific about type or colour (or their own name), they don't specify that it is type or colour that they are specific about, but for basically any other characteristic they will specify what kind of characteristic they are referring to. That's why "search your library for a creature card" could never be used to find a card which has the name "Creature", but not the type (if R&D were short-sighted enough to ever print one), even though to anyone not used to the conventions of MTG wording it clearly would be a "creature card".

Comment: @Andrew (3 comments up) I don't think I understand what you're getting at. When you say "cards that work that way", what kinds of cards exactly do you mean? It sounds as if you're saying an ability "T: Untap target land named Forest" would nevertheless be able to target any land with the Forest type, and I'm pretty sure that's not the case (i.e. not true, but also presumably not what you meant).

Comment: It should be pointed out that at least the original dual lands didn't have the subtype; they had explicit text saying they count as both.

Comment: @DavidZ I believe he's saying that most cards that intend to be restricted to "cards named Forest" do so by restricting to "basic Forests", which is equivalent. This isn't quite correct, because of Snow-covered Forest, but it's usually true in standard and limited.

Comment: @DavidZ, Eyeballfrog is correct, I have never seen a card look at lands by name, always by some type set. And yes, basic forest would apply to snow covered as well, though for the most part those are functionally equivalent (not many play things in any format that will care about snow)

Comment: @Andrew There's a Zo-Zu The Punisher EDH deck that wants to run Snow-covered Mountains because it runs Extraplanar Lens, and it allows you to get extra red mana from your Mountains, likely without also giving the same benefit to any players in the game also running red.
I guess that isn't a good example because it isn't that it actually cares about snow, but rather that it's functionally a Mountain except with a different name, and it cares about the name.

Comment: @0xFFF1 i do know about lens, and tgat decks using it usually run snow, but it doesnt really invalidate anything i said, not to mention ive seen decks not using lens use snow because they could stel someone else's lense benefit.

Comment: @Arthur I think the reason for specifying things like cmc when talking about a card is they have to. Red is a color, creature is a type, but '3' is just a number, that could equally be CMC, power or toughness, so they have to specify which. Card named X gets around possible self referential confusion that could have happened with say Squadron Hawk, and possible name/type overlap, as can happens with basic land types (though here they usually don't reference name, but say basic X, to include snow covered versions)

Answer (score 13):

Forest is a Subtype for the card Type "Land".

Thus, Arbor Elf can untap any land with the subtype Forest. Which include the Basic Land, Forest, its respective Snow-Covered version and some non-basic lands that include this subtype in their text line.

[This Gatherer search](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&subtype=%20[%22Forest%22]) shows a list of 17 lands with the subtype Forest:

These are all the lands that can be untapped by Arbor Elf. Note that some cards like [Song of the Dryads](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSong%20of%20the%20Dryads%5d) can turn other permanent into Forests, thus allowing it to be untapped by Arbor Elf.

Comment: Worth noting that Forest is also the name of a card in addition to being a land subtype. Things that look for cards named Forest will not work on those other lands.

Comment: Also, if somehow any of those cards, including Forest, lost the Forest subtype, it would not be eligible to untap via Arbor Elf, even if it still has the T: add G to your mana. ability.

Comment: @corsiKa it's the subtype that gives those lands "T: add G"